# Prevent user uploading under the root instead use folders within

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, permissions

I have document library "Records" and I have 20 folders. I want users to upload file under those folders and not directly under the library. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove users' edit permissions on the library level, and only grant them edit permission on the folder level.

Below article would help you:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427bd7c-f20a-4f75-8cf2-5359dd45a1a6